# How Can I Shorten This?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am trying to create the marks needed for this graph and this process is very lengthy. Is there a shorter way I could do this? I am trying to create a mark at every 1/6 mark between 1 and 6 so that I can place each interval.
Here is what I'm trying to create:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
   \draw [-] (0,0)--coordinate(x axis mid)(6,0);
   \foreach\x/\xtext in {0,{1/6}/{1/6},{2/6}/{2/6},
   {3/6}/{3/6},{4/6}/{4/6},{5/6}/{5/6},1,{7/6}/{7/6},6}
    \draw[shift={(\x,0)}] (0pt,0pt)--(0pt,-2pt);
   \draw [-] (0,0)--coordinate(y axis mid)(0,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I need to just hardcode everything then just let me know.

Comment: Can you give a better example of what the goal is? There is a smooth curve is it a closed form formula? What is the zigzagged line? Is that coming from a data source?

Comment: I can create the graph its self, but the labels at the bottom of the graph {13-47}, I've had to type in each marks, and I assume there's a shorter way to type it all in.

Comment: Ah by marks you mean tick labels?

Comment: Exactly, I thought they were referred to as tick labels.

Comment: I fixed my problem by putting the tick marks in increments by decimal instead of fractions.

Comment: @Bmarc20 If you could put your solution as an answer to this question, it would be helpful for future readers.

Comment: the title of your post is absolutely useless. Be more specific please

Comment: @pluton The title is for the graph I created afterwards, not for what I had a problem with.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you put the ticks down without having to type them in one at a time by hand.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
   \draw [-] (0,0)--coordinate(x axis mid)(5.54,0);
   \draw [-] (0,4)--coordinate(x axis mid)(5.54,4);
   \draw [-] (0,0)--coordinate(y axis mid)(0,4);
   \draw [-] (0,0.8)--coordinate(y axis mid)(5.54,0.8) node[left] at (0,0.8) {11};
   \draw [-] (0,1.6)--coordinate(y axis mid)(5.54,1.6) node[left] at (0,1.6) {12};
   \draw [-] (0,2.4)--coordinate(y axis mid)(5.54,2.4) node[left] at (0,2.4) {13};
   \draw [-] (0,3.2)--coordinate(y axis mid)(5.54,3.2) node[left] at (0,3.2) {14};
   \draw [-] (5.54,-.06)--coordinate(y axis mid)(5.54,4) node[left] at (0,4) {15};
   \foreach\x/\xtext in {0,.167,.33,...,5.54} \draw[shift={(\x,0)}] (0pt,0pt)--(0pt,-2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It will look like this when finished.

[image]